# Where should startup scripts for a specific user be installed?

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, filesystems

I have one script that will run when a specific user logs in. Where should this script and its assets be placed? I was planning to put it in /usr or /bin or /var, but I was wondering if there's a standard for this sort of thing, and where they should be placed to be out of the way but accessible.

Comment: Usually it is put in the user's home directory.  Is there some reason you don't want to do this? If so, change the question to expand upon this.

Comment: No, that basically answers the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Startup scripts and assets are usually put in the user's home directory.

(The home directory can either be found by `getent passwd username` or by logging in as the user and inspecting the value of $HOME.)

Comment: When searching for user information, remember to use `getent passwd` (instead of only `grep`ing `/etc/passwd`) to cover cases where the user information might have been loaded from a remote user directory like LDAP or NIS.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a executable script, it is good to place it at `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

**Advantage:**

- avoid typing full path of the script like `/var/opt/anything/my_script`
- ever you want to test it from terminal , just type my_script

I think there is no standard of doing this, place it anywhere (obviously not at `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/var/www`, etc.) you like, finally it depends on your choice.